# How to configure xcode output text?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, console

When you use for exemple:

```
NSLog(@"test");
```

The console print:

```
"2012-03-29 08:12:13.735 testApp[446:f803] test"
```

How to have only the "test" without "2012-03-29 08:12:13.735 testApp[446:f803]" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf("test\n");`.